# Do groups generated by round functions generate the alternating group?

Tags: block-cipher, symmetric, group-theory

Let $K,X$ be sets and let $F:K\times X\rightarrow X$ be a function. For each $k\in K$, let $f_{k}:X\rightarrow X$ be the function where $f_{k}(x)=F(k,x)$ whenever $k\in K,x\in X$. Assume that each $f_{k}$ is a bijection.

Suppose that $F$ is the round function for some cryptographic function such as AES-128 or some cryptographic function.

If $F$ is a cryptographic function, then I do not expect for $\{f_{k}\mid k\in K\}$ to generate the full symmetric group $S_{X}$, but I would expect for $\{f_{k}\mid k\in K\}$ to generate the alternating group $A_{X}$ (let me know if there are any real-world examples where $f_{k}$ is an odd permutation). Has there been cases in cryptography where it was rigorously proven that $\{f_{k}\mid k\in K\}$ generates or does not generate the alternating group $A_{X}$? For example, if
$F$ is the round function for AES-128 or DES, then does $\{f_{k}|k\in K\}$ generate the alternating group $A_{X}$?

I am mainly interested in the case where the functions $f_{k}$ are the round functions because this case will probably be easier to analyze and because if the functions $f_{k}$ are the round functions, then it is more likely that $\{f_{k}\mid k\in K\}$ generates the alternating group.

This problem may be intractible in most cases, but there may be cases where one can show that
$\{f_{k}\mid k\in K\}$ generates the alternating group $A_{X}$ such as outdated or insecure cryptography or when the cryptography has a special form that makes it easier to analyze (such as Feistel ciphers) or even cryptographic algorithms that are designed for testing.

We say that a subgroup $G$ of the permutation group $S_{X}$ is $n$-transitive if whenever $x_{1},\dots,x_{n}$ are distinct elements in $X$ and $y_{1},\dots,y_{n}$ are distinct elements in $X$, then there is some $g\in G$ with $g(x_{i})=y_{i}$ whenever $1\leq i\leq n$.

> Theorem: Suppose that $X$ is finite and $|X|>24$. If $G$ is a
> $4$-transitive subgroup of $S_{X}$, then either $G=S_{X}$ or
> $G=A_{X}$.

The above theorem may make it easier to prove that $G=A_{X}$.

If $\{f_{k}\mid k\in K\}$ does not generate the alternating group $A_{X}$, then I would reject any block cipher with round function $F$ as being horribly insecure since either $|X|\leq 24$ which is too small for any block cipher or the group generated by $\{f_{k}\mid k\in K\}$ is not 4-transitive.

However, if it is easy or tractible to prove that $\{f_{k}\mid k\in K\}$ generates the alternating group $A_{X}$, then the function $F$ may be too well behaved for cryptographic purposes.

Comment: "let me know if there are any real-world examples where $f_k$ is an odd permutation"; several Format Preserving Encryption algorithms (which often is used with very short messages) use a round functions that may be odd - one example would be FF1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example, if $F$ is the round function for AES-128 or DES, then does $\{f_k | k \in K \}$ generate the alternating group $A_X$?

In the case of DES, then, yes it is known that the round function does generate the alternating group, as shown in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-47555-9_9.pdf) ("The One-Round Functions of the DES Generate the Alternating Group" by Ralph Wernsdorf).

I do not believe that any similar result is known for AES.

Comment: Ralph Wernsdorf wrote a similar paper for RIJNDAEL that shows that the round permutations also generate the alternating group there https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-45661-9_11.

Comment: @JosephVanName: thank you; I was unaware of that paper